# How do I get the remote address of a client in org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

how can I access the remote address of the request like request.getRemoteAddr() in an HttpServletRequest within a org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEventListener:
org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent.onEvent(RequestEvent event)?

I'm using Jersey 2.16

Regards